# Android XML serialization

Tags: android, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to Serialize an object in my application by using the Simple Xml Serialization.(http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php). I am trying to serialize my person class but when I run it on my device I cannot find the xml file I have created. Please see my code below:

Person Class:

```
public class Person {

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String inFirstName, String inLastName) {
        SetFirstname(inFirstName);
        SetLastname(inLastName);
    }

    private String FirstName;

    public String GetFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void SetFirstname(String inFirstName) {
        FirstName = inFirstName;
    }

    private String LastName;

    public String GetLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void SetLastname(String inLastName) {
        LastName = inLastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object inObject) {
        if (inObject instanceof Person) {
            Person inPerson = (Person) inObject;
            return this.FirstName.equalsIgnoreCase(inPerson.FirstName)
                    && this.LastName.equalsIgnoreCase(inPerson.LastName);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Person person1 = new Person("billy", "boontay");

        File xmlFile = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Person.xml");

        try {

            Serializer serializer = new Persister();

            serializer.write(person1, xmlFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? And before anyone suggests it I have already added the write external storage permission to my manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File xmlFile = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Person.xml");
```

As I remember, the method getFilrsDir() will return the app folder path, which in data/data folder and you can only find it if you have rooted your device,
try this:

```
File xmlFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +  "/Person.xml");
```

And may be you also need some annocate in your Person class:

```
@root (name = "person") <br>
public class Person {

    @Element (entry = "firstname")
    private String FirstName;
    @Element (entry = "lastname")
    private String LastName;

}
```

Hope this help.